# Endless RecyclerView with multiple view types items duplicating on scrolling up

Tags: android

I have a recycler view with multiple view types and pagination enabled. Scrolling up after two pages the items are not holding the view and are duplicating. I have implemented getItemId return unique id and getViewtype return unique value. Also have the the adapter's setHasStableIds to true. Looking forward for any help.

```
  init {
       setHasStableIds(true)
   }
```

**getItemId**

```
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
       if (postList.get(position).getId()== null){
        return position;
    } else{
        return list.get(position).getId();
    }
```

**getItemViewType**

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position == 0) {
            item
        } else {
            if (position == list.size - 1 && isLoadingAdded) {
                loading
            } else {
                item
            }
        }
    }
```

Adapter:

```
class PostListAdapter constructor(
    private val context: Context,
    private var list: MutableList<Post>,
    private val clickListener: PostListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private val item: Int = 0
    private val loading: Int = 1
    private var isLoadingAdded: Boolean = false
    private var retryPageLoad: Boolean = false
    private var errorMsg: String? = ""

    init {
        setHasStableIds(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return if (viewType == item) {
            val binding: ItemPostBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.item_post,
                parent,
                false
            )
            PostVH(binding)
        } else {
            val binding: ItemLoadingBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.item_loading,
                parent,
                false
            )
            LoadingVH(binding)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val model = list[position]
        if (getItemViewType(position) == item) {
            val postVH: PostVH = holder as PostVH
            postVH.bind(model)
        } else {
            val loadingVH: LoadingVH = holder as LoadingVH
            if (retryPageLoad) {
                loadingVH.itemRowBinding.loadmoreErrorlayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                loadingVH.itemRowBinding.loadmoreProgress.visibility = View.GONE

                if (errorMsg != null) loadingVH.itemRowBinding.loadmoreErrortxt.text = errorMsg
                else loadingVH.itemRowBinding.loadmoreErrortxt.text =
                    context.getString(R.string.error_msg_unknown)

            } else {
                loadingVH.itemRowBinding.loadmoreErrorlayout.visibility = View.GONE
                loadingVH.itemRowBinding.loadmoreProgress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            loadingVH.itemRowBinding.loadmoreRetry.setOnClickListener {
                showRetry(false, "")
                retryPageLoad()
            }
            loadingVH.itemRowBinding.loadmoreErrorlayout.setOnClickListener {
                showRetry(false, "")
                retryPageLoad()
            }
        }
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return if (list.size > 0) list.size else 0
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position == 0) {
            item
        } else {
            if (position == list.size - 1 && isLoadingAdded) {
                loading
            } else {
                item
            }
        }
    }
    
    inner class PostVH(binding: ItemPostBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        var itemBinding: ItemPostBinding = binding
        fun bind(postInfo: Post?) {
           ...
        }

    }

    fun retryPageLoad() {
        context.loadNextPage()
    }

    class LoadingVH(binding: ItemLoadingBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        var itemRowBinding: ItemLoadingBinding = binding
    }

    fun showRetry(show: Boolean, errorMsg: String) {
        retryPageLoad = show
        notifyItemChanged(list.size - 1)
        this.errorMsg = errorMsg
    }

    fun updateList(postList: MutableList<Post>) {
        this.list = postList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun addAll(PostList: MutableList<Post>) {
        for (post in PostList) {
            add(post)
        }
    }

    fun add(post: Post) {
        list.add(post)
        notifyItemInserted(list.size - 1)
    }

    fun addLoadingFooter() {
        isLoadingAdded = true
        add(Post())
    }

    fun removeLoadingFooter() {
        isLoadingAdded = false

        val position: Int = list.size - 1
        val post: Post = list[position]

        if (post != null) {
            list.removeAt(position)
            notifyItemRemoved(position)
        }
    }

    fun clearList() {
        if (isLoadingAdded) {
            removeLoadingFooter()
        }

        list.clear()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun deleteItem(PostId: Long) {
        val index = list.indexOfFirst {
            it.Post?.id == PostId
        }
        if (index != -1) {
            list.removeAt(index)
            notifyItemRemoved(index)
            notifyItemRangeChanged(index, list.size)
        }
    }

    interface PostListener {
        fun onPostClick(PostSync: Post)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the whole implementation of your adapter? Is it necessary to use stable ids in your case?

Comment: @TimurPanzhiev  I have posted adapter code.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to switch from the current implementation to using ConcatAdapter. Use separate adapters for data and loading indicator. Check this Medium post to start https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/merge-adapters-sequentially-with-mergeadapter-294d2942127a.

In your case it is a problem with data providing i guess, and I'd recommend to remove stable ids implementation, it causes quite a lot of problems very often

Comment: Could you please provide sample code for pagination with concat adapter?

Comment: check this google repo on github https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-paging/tree/main/advanced/end

Comment: How can I resolve this issue without concate adapter?

Comment: try to use immutable list in your adapter